# Groovy regex to validate string with fixed characters followed by numbers

Tags: regex, groovy

Trying to validate string input over a regex in groovy. Regex validation must allow fixed characters M000 followed by numbers or "NA"

I have tried `/^((M00[0-9]|NA){1}/` this validates NA to be true but invalidates M0012345

Expected result is to have a single Regex to validate both "NA" and M00 followed by numbers as valid.

```
def regexStr = /^((M00[0-9]|NA){1}/
return fieldValue.matches(regexStr)
```

Desired results

1. M001245 --valid
2. NA -- valid
3. M0A123 -- Invalid
4. M01345 -- Invalid

Comment: Please paste the Groovy code you have written to match the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current pattern has an incomplete grouping structure as it misses the outer closing parenthesis. You might omit the outer group and make the inner group non capturing `(?:`

You have to repeat matching the digits `[0-9]+` and use an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string. You can omit `{1}` from repeating the group.

If you want to match either one of them, you could use:

```
^(?:M00[0-9]+|NA)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eiVKTw/2)

Comment: Thank you fourth Bird but your Regex with small correction is working `^(?:M00[0-9]+|NA)$` please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @niranjanswamy9428480 That would work if it is only NA or M0012345. Is that the desired result? I read the question as `M000 followed by numbers or "NA"` so M00012345 or M00NA. I have updated the answer with the second pattern as well.

Comment: Yes that is the desired result Thank you The fourth bird